# opacity - glubyte

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I have a sprite, and I want to modify the opacity of it to make it transparent.

In some other languages like as2, all I had to do was circle.alpha = 0.5;
I tried circle.opacity = 0.5, but it doesn't work.

I understand that glubyte is a typedef for ={r,g,b,a};

but that's all i understand....nothing more. Not sure how to even look at this data structure.

So, I want to know what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cocos2d, opacity maximum is 255 and minimum is 1.

so you should set your circle to be:

```
circle.opacity = 142;
```